# Using prototype to set array of objects

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have a promise that returns an array of objects from the server. 
What is the best way to define an object with prototype attributes and set these objects array each object to use this prototype in order to save memory?

For example

```
getItems().success(function(data) {
   var items = data;
})
```

Let's say this object has attribute of *detail* and it could have a value or be empty.
So if I'll use a prototype that empty *detail* property of all the objects could use the same reference to the place in memory...

Hope I understood the prototype idea right and that I've managed to explain myself...

Comment: Could you please provide use the full snippet of code where you use your promise and the function where you want to add properties your prototype.... so we can be more specific thanks!

Comment: Do you want to save the promise response in a variable that will be used by any object ?

Comment: Could you be more concrete? Provide sample data which `data` will contain, and then point out in that specific example at which place you feel memory is not efficiently used. NB: "empty" is not a JavaScript term. Do you mean `undefined`? `null`?

Comment: If that is really a promise, you should be using `.then` not `.success`

Comment: Don't worry about saving memory by using prototypes. Memory is essentially free unless you have millions of objects.

Answer (score 1):

> Hope I understood the prototype idea right

No. It doesn't save any memory for data.

The prototype object should only be used for properties that are shared by *all* instances, not when "some instances have it and some don't". A typical example of such shared properties are methods.

Unless you don't have any actual issues with memory, [don't try to optimise anything](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premature_optimisation) here.

Comment: I completely I agree with your latest statement "Unless you don't have any actual issues with memory, don't try to optimise anything".

Answer (score -1):

Generally, you can use the following code to add a property to your function/object prototype.

```
yourObject.prototype.yourProperty = 'yourValue';
```

Promises are my nature asynchronous, so when your promise is fulfilled you can change the value of your object property in the `prototype`, which in return will update all your object instances.

A generic example using native Promise:

```js
var Class = function() {};
Class.prototype.data = 1;

new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
setTimeout(function() {
  resolve(10);
}, 3000);
  })
  .then(function(result) {
Class.prototype.data = result;
console.log('a fulfilled', a.data);
console.log('b fulfilled', b.data);
  })

var a = new Class();
var b = new Class();
console.log('a pending', a.data);
```

More about [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Promise.jsm/Promise).

More about [Object.protoype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype).

Comment: What if I called this just after the request and the request still in progress ;)

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH define yourObject.prototype.data  = null; when the Promise is Fulfilled set yourObject.prototype.data = data;

Comment: The assignment is async and I need the value let's say sync !!! I don't think you get it !

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH thanks for your comment, I have edited my answer with a  more clear example. Maybe if you can provide a jsfiddle with your idea, I would love get your point through thanks.

Comment: Please add a comment when down voting so I can improve my answer. Thanks guys!